# Insight of toString method

Tags: java

Can you please explain what does the following line of code means

```
getClass().getName+"@"+Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

This is how `toString()` method is implemented in Object class but I cannot able to understand how it can call `hashCode()`.

Comment: Becuase `hashCode()` is in the same class. It's the same as `this.hashCode()`.

Comment: can u please elaborate it is still not clear

Comment: I believe you have a typo... `getClass().getName` should be `getClass().getName()`  Since getName is a method, not a field.

Comment: It is calling `hashCode()` the same way it's calling `getClass()`. Nothing is different, really. The fact that `hashCode()` is used as an argument for `toHexString()` is irrelevant.

Comment: A method can call another method.  Can you explain why this is unclear @Shubh?  The `hashCode()` method isn't special.

Answer (score 1):

This returns a string consisting of 3 parts.

1. the name of the class
2. the '@' character
3. the hash code of the object. hashCode() is another method of the Object class (and thus all other objects inherit it, since everything is a subclass of Object).

You can read more at the java api docs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

Any instance of a class is allowed to invoke it's own methods by calling them directly.  You could do `this.getClass()` or `getClass()` or `this.hashCode()` or `hashCode()`.

`getClass().getName()` is the reflection (Reflection is a program's ability to inspect itself at runtime) way to get the name of the class from the running program.  The result of that is then concatenated with the string `"@"` and the other string which is the hexadecimal string representation of the native `hashCode()` implementation.